# ContourPlot of function returning blank

Tags: plotting

I am trying to use ContourPlot to plot a relationship but am not having any luck. When I run:

```
ContourPlot[x == BHertz3[0, {x, y, 0}][[1]] /. values, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 
  10}]
```

I just get a blank canvas. But when I hard code the relationship and plot it:

```
ContourPlot[x == -((10 y)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)), {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

I get a plot. The relationship I am trying to plot works as

```
x == BHertz3[0, {x, y, 0}][[1]] /. values
```

returns

```
x == -((10 y)/(Abs[x]^2 + Abs[y]^2)^(3/2))
```

I have tried using replacement rules to remove the absolute values as shown below:

```
x == BHertz3[0, {x, y, 0}][[1]] /. values /. {Abs[x] -> x, Abs[y] -> y}
```

which returns

```
x == -((10 y)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))
```

but still it returns a blank canvas when plotted.

Anyone know what is wrong?

To reproduce:

```
values = {L -> 10, f -> 18.83/2 \[Pi] , \[Omega] -> 18.83, j0 -> 1 , c -> 1}

BHertz3[t_, {x1_, x2_, x3_}] := {1/
   c^2 j0 L Abs[
    x2] (-( c/(Abs[x1]^2 + Abs[x2]^2 + Abs[x3]^2)^(3/2))) x2/Abs[x2], 
  1/c^2 j0 L Abs[x1] (c/(Abs[x1]^2 + Abs[x2]^2 + Abs[x3]^2)^(3/2)) x1/
    Abs[x1], 0}

ContourPlot[
 x == BHertz3[0, {x, y, 0}][[1]] /. values, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 
  10}]
```

Comment: `ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[x == BHertz3[0, {x, y, 0}][[1]] /. values], {x, -10, 
  10}, {y, -10, 10}]`